# Java - Generating RSA key pair from 5 CRT components

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, bouncycastle

I have 5 CRT components - primeP, primeQ, primeExponentP, primeExponentQ and crtCoefficient. Is there a way we can generate RSA key pair from these?

When I looked at RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec and RSAPublicKeySpec, the missing parameters are modulus, privateExponent and publicExponent.

Can someone help me how to calculate modulus, privateExponent and publicExponent?

Is there a Bouncy Castle implementation to do this?

Thanks!
Sam

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that should be possible. Well unless the public exponent is really large, but that's unlikely.

You can probably guess (i.e. try 3, 5, 7, 13, 17 and 65537) or brute force the public exponent - as it's usually a small prime. The 65537 value (0x010001, the fourth Fermat prime) is most likely. Then you can [calculate the private exponent](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19407/calculate-the-rsa-private-exponent-from-the-crt-parameters). You can verify your guess using sign/verify with the key pair.

Note that it is kinda weird that you do have the CRT parameters but not the public key. Actually, that's so weird that you probably have to code this yourself.

Comment: Thanks, Maarten. Do you know if we can do this using Bouncy Castle?

Comment: I did the opposite: calculate the public key and CRT parameters from the private key. Useful to speed up calculations afterwards (sorry, I'm a bit tired, indicated that you should try public exponent 0x010001 first).

Answer (score 0):

Just supply nulls for the missing parameters in the CRT spec. The key factory will figure it out.

```
RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec privateSpec = new RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec(null, null, null, p, q, expP, expQ, coeff);
KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey)factory.generatePrivate(privateSpec);
```

The modulus is primeP * primeQ. In most cases, the public exponent is 65537.